# Delete rows from CTE in SQL SERVER

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a CTE which is a select statement on a table.  Now if I delete 1 row from the CTE, will it delete that row from my base table?

Also is it the same case if I have a temp table instead of CTE?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Checking the [DELETE statement documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189835%28v=SQL.105%29.aspx), **yes**, you can use a CTE to delete from and it will affect the underlying table.  Similarly for UPDATE statements...

> Also is it the same case if I have a temp table instead of CTE?

No, deletion from a temp table will affect the temp table only -- there's no connection to the table(s) the data came from, a temp table is a stand alone object.

Comment: How does CTE differ from Temp table in this scenario?

Comment: @satyajit: A temp table is a table (can have different scopes: local, global) that stores data in the TEMPDB (rather than the DB it was created in).  A CTE is a derived table/inline view, that exists only for the scope of the query it is declared in -- using resources from the current DB.

Answer (score 3):

You can think of CTE as a subquery, it doesn't have a temp table underneath.
So, if you run delete statement against your CTE you will delete rows from the table. Of course if SQL can infer which table to upadte/delete base on your CTE. Otherwise you'll see an error.

If you use temp table, and you delete rows from it, then the source table will not be affected, as temp table and original table don't have any correlation.

Comment: So, Will it be correct to say that CTE works as a temporary view

Comment: @satyajit - You can say that. It will not lead to any db object creation though. Temp table on the contrary will lead to creation a table in tempdb and physical copying data to the table from your source tables.

Answer (score 0):

In the cases where you have a sub query say joining multiple tables and you need to use this in multiple places then both cte and temp table can be used. If you however want to delete records based on the sub query condition then cte is the way to go.  Sometimes you can simply use the delete statement with out a need of cte since it's a delete statement and only rows that satisfy the query conditions get deleted even though multiple conditions are used for filtering.